# Bengali Font is not showing using jsPDF library

Tags: utf-8, jspdf, bengali

I'm using jsPDF in Angular. Unable to show Bengali font in the generated PDF but only English font is showing.

Comment: Details : The problem is, in Hindi and in Bengali (my use case) fonts can "merge" - ie ফি is typed ফ and then the umbrella-like character. A better way to understand is for you to copy ফি into a text editor and press backspace once. The character will loose its "umbrella" and become ফ. ie the umbrella is typed after the character but on screen, it is shown behind the character.